# R zoo::na.fill not filling

Tags: r, na, zoo

`zoo::na.fill` refuses to fill on character vector when there is any non-NA value. Is this a bug or is it as designed?

```
> packageVersion("zoo")
[1] ‘1.8.0’
> zoo::na.fill(c(NA, NA, 'Jan'), fill = 'None') # not working
[1] NA    NA    "Jan"
> zoo::na.fill(c(NA, NA), fill = 'None') # all NA, fills ok
[1] "None" "None"
> zoo::na.fill(c(NA, NA, 3), fill = 0) # numerical value ok
[1] 0 0 3
```

Comment: I can't reproduce with zoo 1.8.1.

Comment: I can't reproduce that with 1.8-1 (the CRAN version) either.  With 1.8-1 it works as expected for me.

Comment: yes, works in 1.8.1. Although this is not mentioned in version change log

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, it does work.

```
> packageVersion("zoo")
[1] ‘1.8.1’
> zoo::na.fill(c(NA, NA, 'Jan'), fill = 'None')
[1] "None" "None" "Jan"
```

Comment: No, it's not normal. `zoo(c(NA, NA, 'Jan'))` works just fine.

Comment: too quick answering it.. Not sure though what you can do with `zoo` with character vector..